# RS485 Wrong Results in Serial Monitor(Controllino) - Right Results with Logic Analyzer

Tags: rs485

After searching the internet and trying different examples, I always get the same wrong response in the serial monitor.

Picture 1 shows the wrong results. At first i thought it was decimal and I just had to convert it to ASCII. But that wasn't the problem.

Picture 2 shows the results that I expect. It's from the Logic Analyzer that sits on a breadbord to "sniff" the communication.
I expect N+0000.0\r

Picture 3 shows the settings or the logic analyzer. Please ignore the "SPI MISO" it's just an old description.

I have no other approach left in my mind.

I would appreciate any hint. :) Thank you in advance.

You will find the Arduino sketch below the pictures.

[image: Serial Monitor]

[image: Logic Analyzer]

[image: Settings Logic Analyzer]

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Controllino.h>  /* Usage of CONTROLLINO library allows you to use CONTROLLINO_xx aliases in your sketch. */

const int numBytes = 20;
int incomingBytes[numBytes];   // for incoming serial data


void setup() {

  /* Initialize serial port for debug messages. */
  Serial.begin(9600);

  /* Initialize CONTROLLINO RS485 direction control DE/RE pins and Serial3 */
Serial3.begin(9600,SERIAL_8N2); //Initialisierung Serial Controllino(RS 485)
  //Beim Mega oder Maxi Zugang zum /OVL pin und RS458 /RE DE Pins
  //Zuweisung /RE (PJ5) DE (PJ6) pins als Ausgang (1). Für /OLV (PE7) als Eingang (0)
  DDRJ |= B01100000;
  DDRE &= B01111111;

  //Controllino_RS485Init(9600);
  //Controllino_RS485RxEnable();

  Serial.println("Recieving RS485...");
}

void loop() {

DatenEmpfangen();
delay(1000);  
DatenAnzeigen();
}


void DatenEmpfangen()
{
  static byte ndx = 0;
  int rc;
  PORTJ &= B10011111;//Empfangen MODUS
  //Controllino_RS485RxEnable();
  delay(1000);
  do
  {
    if (Serial3.available() > 0)
    {
     // digitalWrite(CONTROLLINO_D1, HIGH);
     rc = Serial3.read();

     incomingBytes[ndx] = rc;
     ndx++;
    }
  } while (Serial3.available() > 0);
}


void DatenAnzeigen()
{
  static byte count = 0;
  //int Xor = 0;
  //Xor = receivedIntegersA[0];
  Serial.println("Daten");
  for (count=0;count<9;count++)
  {
    Serial.println((incomingBytes[count]));
  }


}
```

Comment: first chage type of incomingBytes to byte (for printing). use println(incomingBytes [count] , HEX)

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: @ Juraj - that doesn't work. The Hex Values are completely different compared to the correct output of the logic analyzer.

Comment: @Majenko - i don't get any output at all. I uploaded the sketch here: https://github.com/AndreasNRW/WS_RS485

Comment: @Majenko - i'm sorry, your linked example works great. The terminating character in my case was \r not \n. Very nice blog post. Thanks a lot.